# advanced json-schema multiple rules per property

Tags: json, node.js, jsonschema

I'm wondering if you can have multiple rules for a property.  All the examples seem to suggest you can't.

So I'd like to have something like:

```
"properties": {
  "track": {
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "(exclusive)"
  },
  "track": {
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "(featuring)"
  }
}
```

I know the obvious thing to do in this example would be to have pattern be to have `"(exclusive)|(featuring)"`, but i guess i'd want to know which rule failed. Equally I might want more complex patterns later down the line which might not be solved by a `|`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine schemas with the `allOf`, `anyOf`, and `oneOf` keywords. Each of these keywords takes an array of schemas and does what it says it does. `allOf` is valid if *all of* the schemas are valid. `anyOf` is valid if *any of* the schemas are valid. `oneOf` is valid if exactly *one of* the schemas are valid.

Here's one approach your problem.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "track": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "(exclusive)"
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "(featuring)"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oha, nice one and might be handier than my list of dictionary solution depending on the context.